# Inteprolating/resampling one point layer onto another in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have two point layers. The orange points are my source data. I want to interpolate the value of the labelled attribute at the red points. Inverse Distance Weighted (IDW) is good enough.

I thought this would be easy in QGIS, but it seems that the tools related to resampling and interpolation are all raster-based. Is there really no way to just interpolate a point layer via IDW onto another point layer, without creating an intermediate raster?

[image]

Comment: you can make a vector grid (process native:makegrid) - I would choose hexagons - then in the next step the joinbylocationsummary process and finally make centroids from the hexagons...